# How can I set different spawnpoints for different people?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How can I have different spawnpoints for different people, so that new players spawn in a different place to older players?

A new player to the server should spawn at 130 53 -203, whereas an old player (connecting for the second time or more) should spawn at 530 60 0.

Answer (score 4):

Well, there is no exact solution for your question (as far as I know...)

you can set the spawn for every player with:

```
/setworldspawn 130 53 -203
```

and additionally set the spawn for this "Old player" with

```
/spawnpoint <playername> 530 60 0
```

Also you can build a clock with a command block doing "spawn point @a 530 60 0"
Note: if this "Older Player" sleeps in an bed, his personal spawnpoint will be reset to this bed. If this bed is destroyed he will spawn on the spawnpoint 130 53 -203

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Bukkit or Spigot to power your Minecraft server, this can be done by using the [Essentials plugin](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/essentials/) and a permissions plugin of your choice (my preferred plugin being [PermissionsEx](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/permissionsex/)).

First, you will need to create two different permissions groups in your permissions plugin. For example, you may have **Default** and **Member** as your first two groups. You would need to mark the **Default** group as being your default group for new players who connect, and you would need to set up the **Member** group to inherit the permissions for the **Default** group. This varies between different permissions plugins, but it isn't hard to find out. The plugin documentation should cover it somewhere for whatever plugin you decide to use.

Once you've created your two groups, you can use the `/setspawn` command in Essentials to set different spawnpoints for different permissions groups.

For our two examples mentioned above, you would type the following commands:

```
/setspawn Default
/setspawn Member
```

Essentials would recognize that you have two different permissions groups with these names, and it would make it so that if a player types `/spawn`, it will take them to the proper place that you have designated.

Just make sure you've given the permission node `essentials.spawn` to your default group so they can use the command in the first place!

Answer (score 0):

Estimated answer of mine:
First, setworldspawn a coordinate.
Next,
Command block: status: always active, repeating
Command:

> /execute @a (coordinates) /spawnpoint

Comment: `/execute` is not necessary, which is shown in the top-rated answer.